# "hide keyboard" button not hiding the keyboard on iPad simulator

Tags: ipad, keyboard, uitextfield, uitextview

I have this really strange problem. In my problem, I have a navigation view controller, which pushes my original view controller to another one (let's call it AViewController)

There is an xib file attached to it. In the xib, there are 2 textfields and 1 textview.
I've made sure that all the connections are correct, so are the memory management stuff.

The problem is that when I press inside the textview, a keyboard shows up (which is normal). But the "dismiss keyboard" button on the bottom right corner is not responding. I can see that when I press the button once, it changes color, but not the consecutive ones. And may be after i move a the mouse a little bit, and press it again, it changes color when I press the button again. (when I say change color, it is that usual change in color of the button when you press a button).

The 2 textfields are working fine; the keyboards are hiding when I press the "dismiss keybaord" button. Only the textview is not working.

I've also checked the delegation piece. I made that if the background is touched, the resignfirst responder will be called, and it works (the keyboard will disappear when the background is touched), but it won't disappear when the "dismiss keyboard" button is pressed.
The "textviewdidendediting" is also called only after I press the background(when resignfirstresponder is called), but not called when "dismiss keybaord" button is pressed.

I've tried the following answers, but nothing worked so far:
[Dismiss keyboard on IPAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316700/dismiss-keyboard-on-ipad)

the "dismiss keybaord button is this: 
[detect iPad keyboard Hiding button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532846/detect-ipad-keyboard-hiding-button)
(I don't want to mess with the button, i just want the keyboard to disappear normally when cliked that button)

again, i have 2 other textfields in the screen working fine. No method is called to the delegate when the button is pressed

Hope someone could help.

Comment: About the only thing that I can think of that would prevent it from disappearing is if you have over-ridden `textViewShouldEndEditing` in its' delegate.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. What i can add is that in my case, my UITextView is inside a UITableViewCell and that the view is being displayed as modal. I don't have any delegation or action linked to the viewcontroller and the keyboards keeps not getting hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {


            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
    }
```